# Java Árbol contar numero menores

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al contar el numero de nodos que hay menores a un dato introducido por pantalla.

Ejemplo de árbol:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir del código para contar el numero total de nodos he intentado sacar el que cuente solo los menores a ese dato:

```
    private int getMenores(int dato, NodoArbol nodo){
        int contador=0;
        if(nodo!=null){
            if(nodo.getData().getNumero()<dato)
                contador++;
        }
        if(nodo.getLeft()!=null){
            if(nodo.getLeft().getData().getNumero()<dato)
            contador +=getMenores(dato,nodo.getLeft());
        }
        if(nodo.getRight()!=null){
            if(nodo.getRight().getData().getNumero()<dato)
            contador +=getMenores(dato,nodo.getRight());
        }
        return contador;
    }
```

El problema llega en la ejecución y no muy bien porque en algunos casos muestra el dato real y en otros no:

> Si introduzco como dato 0 sale 0 **(está bien)**
>
> Si introduzco como dato 10 sale 0 **(está mal)**
>
> Si introduzco como dato 30 sale 3 **(está bien)**
>
> Si introduzco como dato 40 sale 4 **(está bien)**
>
> Si introduzco como dato 50 sale 4 **(está mal)**
>
> Si introduzco como dato 60 sale 5 **(está mal)**
>
> Si introduzco como dato 70 sale 7 **(está bien)**
>
> Si introduzco como dato 80 sale 8 **(está bien)**

Si alguien sabe que me esta fallando y me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que para calcular el número de nodos con valor de clave menor a un valor dado conviene usar la invariante de los árboles binarios de búsqueda. Es decir, los valores del subárbol izquierdo de cualquier nodo son inferiores al valor del nodo, y los del subárbol derecho, superiores. Eso implica que el recorrido inorden del árbol nos da los valores de clave por orden ascendente. Y por tanto podemos recorrerlo hasta encontrar el primero superior. En el ejemplo que te adjunto, por legibilidad se recorre todo el árbol almacenando en una lista la seqcuencia ascendiente de sus valores. Luego con un while se busca el primero superior. Podría mejorarse dejando de recorrer el árbol en cuanto se encuentre el pprimer valor superior, para ello, cabría añadir una variable booleana en la rutina getMenores.

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private static List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();

private void recorre_ascedientemente(NodoArbol nodo){
    if (nodo == null) return;
    recorre_ascendientemente(nodo.getLeft());
    lista.add(nodo.getData());
    recorre_ascendientemente(nodo.getRight());
}
private int getMenores(int dato, NodoArbol nodo) {
    recorre_ascendientemente(nodo);
    int i=0;
    while (i < lista.length() && dato < lista.get(i)) i++;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, es una solución distinta a la que yo había pensado pero me la apunto por si alguna la vez la necesito

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en tus `if`

supongamos en el ejemplo que el `dato = 10`

```
 if(nodo.getLeft()!=null){
     if(nodo.getLeft().getData().getNumero()<dato)
         contador +=getMenores(dato,nodo.getLeft());
 }
```

Cuando haces esa evaluación, tenemos que

```
nodo.getLeft().getData() = 24 //ya que es el primer nodo que aparece en la izquierda
data = 10
```

por lo que sustituyendo tenemos qué

```
if(nodo.getLeft()!=null){
    if(24<10)
        contador +=getMenores(dato,nodo.getLeft());
}
```

Si notas jamás entras a la condición, por lo que no recordé los nodos hijos de ese nodo, porque no entró.

La solución es eliminar esos if, ya que contador solo lo estás sumando cuando dicho nodo entra, por lo que el primer if basta para hacerlo, por lo que tu código quedaría

```
private int getMenores(int dato, NodoArbol nodo){
        int contador=0;
        if(nodo!=null){
            if(nodo.getData().getNumero()<dato)
                contador++;
        }
        if(nodo.getLeft()!=null){
            contador +=getMenores(dato,nodo.getLeft());
        }
        if(nodo.getRight()!=null){
            contador +=getMenores(dato,nodo.getRight());
        }
        return contador;
    }
```

Con eso debería funcionar

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, era eso. Ya no aparecen los errores de antes

Comment: La solución de Sr1871 tiene el inconveniente de que peta al llamarse con un nulo, después del "if (nodo != null)" inicial, puesto que si es nulo, peta al prguntar por getLeft().